# Custom alerts for document library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

Currently the alerts set shows so many unwanted details in a document library. 
Can it be customized to show only the newly added folders or files with a custom alerts or using SharePoint designer.

I would prefer to have an email sent as soon as an item or a folder is added to the Document library. The challenges i am facing is that  if i start the workflow when an item is created , when i copy a whole folder of files it will fire a lot of emails

Answer (score 0):

You could create a workflow in designer with the logic.

if Current Item: Created equals today
send email to (relevant person)

This will email them every time a new item is created and you can include all relevant information in the email. Sorry if I've misunderstood your question

Comment: You have understood it correctly. I would prefer to have an email sent as soon as an item or a folder is added to the Document library. The challenges i am facing is that  if i start the workflow when an item is created , when i copy a whole folder of files it will fire a lot of emails

Comment: hmm I'm not entirely sure on this but wouldn't copying the list essentially create it under a new id and not be effected by the workflow? Could be wrong as I don't really have experience in copying lists

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably have to write a custom workflow for this in Visual Studio to get the expected behavior.  Something like number of items is greater than 1 then do this activity else do this.